# Infinite Sums within Matrix Factorizations?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I came across the following equations on Continuous Markov Chains ( P(t) is the time-dependent transition matrix for the Markov Chain):

[image]

**I am trying to understand how you are supposed to go from the second last step to the last step.** I understand that the general purpose of these equations is to show that the matrix P(t) can be factorized using Eigenvalue Decomposition - **but I am not sure as to how this infinite sum (in the second last step) can be reduced into a finite-sized vector (in the last step).**

- Is there some standard matrix identity that demonstrates why this is true? Can someone please help me understand this?

Thank you!

Comment: It is just saying that $\sum_n [A_{ij}(n)] = [ \sum_n A_{ij} (n) ]$.

Comment: @ copper.hat: thank you for your reply! can you please clarify this a bit more? how does this identity you have stated demonstrate that an infinite sum can be reduced into a finite sized vector? does this have anything to do with geometric series? thank you so much!

Comment: Short answer: the diagonal matrix is of finite size, with entries whose terms are related to the expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: There is no reduction of any sort, it is purely syntactical. Just as $[A+B]_{ij} = [A]_{ij}+ [B]_{ij}$, the same applies to infinite sums (assuming they make sense).